# Range of water undertow in a differential pressure ($\Delta p$) situation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, estimation

I hope this is the right forum for it (otherwise I'll happily move my question to the correct one).

I recently read about a number of diving incidents involving a delta p situation. All those reports showed that the incidents happened only in close proximity to the passage that connected two tanks of water (the diver was in one of them). I'm not really an engeneer or a scientist but I tried to find a formular to calculate the range of the undertow (but wasn't successfull). Can anybody tell me which formular to use in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a safety related question, please note that you must not rely on this answer for anything of any practical consequence. I am not a diver, and this is a theoretical and approximate answer. Given what's at stake I suspect the answer is simply don't go anywhere near them.

The *total water flow* is conserved for any suface covering the passage mouth.

The water *flow per unit area* falls in proportion to the surface area, to maintain constant *total water flow*.

If your cave entrance is a circle of radius $r_a$ (which it isn't) we can define a hemispherical surface of $r_s=r_a$ and determine the relative areas.

The flow rate ratio is given by the inverse surface area ratio

$$ \frac{F_s}{F_a} = \frac{3 A}{2 \pi r_s^3} $$

Where A is the aperture cross sectional area.

Or, you can expect the flow rate to drop off pretty sharply at $\frac{1}{r^3}$ where this model is valid for $r > r_a$.

To determine a safe radius, we have to assume a safe flow rate. Say $F_s=0.5m/s$.

$$ r_s^3 = \frac{3}{\pi}A F_a$$

$$ r_s = \sqrt[3]{\frac{3AF_a}{\pi}} $$

It may be appropriate to include a safety margin, or safety factor, that is of a size commensurate to the overall magnitude of risk presented by the specific hazard.

Comment: You’re using the volume of a sphere for your surface area of hemisphere?

Comment: ah - multiplied my RHSs by two now.

Answer (score 0):

Give Section 6 of [HSE Research Report 761, *Differential pressure hazards in diving*](http://www.hse.gov.uk/research/rrpdf/rr761.pdf) a read.

In it are simple calculations to estimate the size of a "differential pressure danger zone" (DPDZ).

First calculate what the volumetric flow rate $(Q)$ is through the orifice. This can be done a number of ways and is dependent on the specifics of the situation, e.g., if the flow is purely gravity fed or is powered by a pump.  This document shows an estimation based on a gravity feed situation, where the orifice is discharging freely into the atmosphere.  The equation they provide is
$$Q=4.43A \sqrt{D}$$
where $Q=$ volumetric flow rate (m$^3$/s), $A=$ cross-sectional area of the orifice (m$^2$), and $D$ is the depth (or height) of fluid above the orifice (m).  (This equation is simply a form of [Torricelli's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torricelli%27s_law).)  Google "submerged orifice" to see another scenario for gravity-fed flow discharging from one body of water to another.  The volumetric flow rate is then calculated as
$$Q=CA\sqrt{2g(h_1-h_2)}$$
where $C=$ a discharge coefficient (unitless, values range between 0.5 to 1, with a value of 1 being a common assumption), $g=$ gravity acceleration (9.81 m/s$^2$), and $(h_1-h_2)=$ the difference in fluid heights (depths) in meters between the two bodies of water on the entry and exit sides of the orifice, respectively. (Note, $\sqrt{2g}=4.43$, which is where the 4.43 coefficient came from in their volumetric rate equation.)

Once the volumetric flow rate through the orifice has been determined, the safe distance from the orifice $(R)$ is estimated as
$$R=\sqrt{Q/\pi}$$
where $R=$ is the radius in meters of a DPDZ around an orifice intake with water velocity of 0.5 m/s.

To see where this last equation came from, note that

$$v=\frac{Q}{A} =\frac{Q}{2 \pi R^2}$$
 
Safe flow velocity is $v=0.5 m/s$
 
Therefore we solve for the safe radial distance as
 
$$0.5 =\frac{Q}{2 \pi R^2}$$
 
$$R=\sqrt{\frac{Q}{0.5 \cdot 2 \pi}}$$
 
$$R=\sqrt{\frac{Q}{\pi}}$$

If you want to use a different threshold velocity $(v)$ for safety, use

$$R=\sqrt{\frac{Q}{2v \pi}}$$

Lastly, as this is a question regarding safety, I will quote the document with regards to the validity of these estimations:

> The actual distance to which a diver may approach a hazard and remain
>   at water velocities below 0.5 m/s is relatively small. However, it
>   must be stressed that the assumptions made in calculating a DPDZ mean
>   there are considerable difficulties in estimating flow velocities in
>   real life scenarios and thus implementing them as a control measure.
>   Irregular shaped openings or intakes, surface effects, vortices and
>   the partial occlusion of intakes can all distort the DPDZ and increase
>   flow velocities. However, as the distances are relatively small,
>   considerable safety margins may be added to calculations and the
>   exclusion areas still remain practicable.

Comment: The last equation doesn't satisfy dimensional analysis. (Not saying its wrong, just it's not a complete scientific answer.). That is Q is in $m^3 /s$ and R is in meters.

Comment: @JMLCarter I don’t have pencil/paper in front of me currently but I suppose it’s some simplified form using the relation that $v=Q/A$ and that surface area of hemisphere normal to direction of flow is $2 \pi R^2$. In any case, good catch!

Comment: @JMLCarter it does satisfy dimensions, see edit